# Show that $B(\alpha,\alpha)=2\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{4}-(\frac{1}{2}-x)^{2})^{\alpha-1}dx$

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function

Show that $B(\alpha,\alpha)=2\int_0^{1/2}(\frac{1}{4}-(\frac{1}{2}-x)^{2})^{\alpha-1}dx$

Where $B(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx$

I tried in many ways

$$B(\alpha,\alpha)
=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(2\alpha)}$$

Trying to apply the legendre's formula: $$\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2\alpha-1}}\Gamma(2\alpha)$$

As well
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)^{2}\right)^{\alpha-1}dx
&=2\int_0^{1/2}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)^{2}\right)^{\alpha-1}dx\\
&=2\int_0^{1/2}(1-x)^{\alpha-1}x^{\alpha-1}dx\\
\end{align*}

but does not seem leading nowhere useful.

Comment: The usual definition is $B(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx$, are you sure you mean $\int_0^\infty\,$?

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong $\int_0^1 $

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the fact that $x-x^2$ is symmetric about the line $x=\frac12$.  Thus the integral equals twice that from $0$ to $\frac12$...